# React native not re-rendering after state change

Tags: react-native, reducers, react-context

I was trying to make an authentication flow using context api and reducer , 
I had a file named GlobalState where I am keeping all my authentication state with tokens.I also had reducer to update the state.
Inside my GlobalState file there is function loginFb which will update the state according to the response from my rest API .
When I try to console the sate I can see that my state is changed after login , but my app is not re-rendering . I am expecting my app to re-render  on  state change and move to HomeStackScreens .

following is my app.js

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, {useContext} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@reactnavigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import HomeTabs from './screens/HomeTabs';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import {GlobalContext, GlobalProvider} from './context/GlobalState';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator();
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthStackScreen = () => {
  return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator screenOptions={{}}>
      <AuthStack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
    </AuthStack.Navigator>
  );
};

const HomeStackScreens = () => {
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#37966f', elevation: 0},
      }}>
      <HomeStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
};

function App() {


  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
    const bootstrapAsync = async () => {
      let userToken;
      console.log('is Signedin :', isSignedIn);

      try {
        userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authTocken');
        if (userToken) console.log('autTocken:' + userToken);
        else console.log('no tocken');
      } catch (e) {

        console.log('no tocken');
      }


    };

    bootstrapAsync();
  }, []);
  const {authState, isSignedIn} = useContext(GlobalContext);
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <NavigationContainer>
        {console.log('from app:', authState, 'signedin', isSignedIn)}
        {isSignedIn ? <HomeStackScreens /> : <AuthStackScreen />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Globalstate.js

```
import React, {createContext, useReducer} from 'react';
import AppReducer from './AppReducers';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

//Initial State

const initialState = {
  authTocken: '',
  refreshTocken: '',
  fbToken: '',
  isSignedIn: false,
};

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);
export const GlobalProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [authState, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);

  async function loginFb(fbToken) {
    // loginFb: async fbToken=>{
    await fetch(
      'https://api_url?accessToken=' +
        fbToken,
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
      },
    )
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then(async function (data) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('authTocken', data.token);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('refreshTocken', data.refreshToken);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('fbToken', fbToken);
        dispatch({
          type: 'SIGN_IN',
          payload: data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('found error', error);
      });
  }
  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider
      value={{authState, loginFb, isSignedIn: authState.isSignedIn}}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

AppReducer.js

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SIGN_IN': {
      return {
        ...state,
        isSignedIn: true,
        refreshTocken: action.payload.refreshToken,
        authTocken: action.payload.token,
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: please provide a code example to make it clearer.

Comment: @RowanX question updated with sample code

Answer (score 1):

instead of having

```
export default App;
```

changed to

```
export default () => (
  <GlobalProvider>
     <App />
   </GlobalProvider>
    )
```

**now its working**